# Button Remains Highlighted after clicked c# (windows form)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Pictures of the button before it is pressed and after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RahOn.jpg

The button that is clicked on opens a new form, stuff happens, and when that form is closed, the button turns to the dark gray.  I do not want this to happen. I want the button to stay the light gray color.

Help?

I am using the metro style buttons.

Comment: Please clarify if this is WPF or WinForms. "Metro style buttons" isn't very descriptive either.

Comment: Post the code that “opens a new form”.

Comment: Maybe u should use toggle button. We dont see your code sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following code in some other place where the OP says he also found it in some other place...

In short,

First step :
Create a new static class, copy the following code:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

   public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
   {
      uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
   }
}
```

Also add

using System.Windows.Threading;

on top of the class

Second Step:
Give your button a name in xaml. e.g:

```
<Button x:Name="myPreciousButton" />
```

In your project, whenever you want the button to turn light grey (or to any default style) again, call:

```
myPreciousButton.Refresh();
```

You can call it on the form closing, if you know when it closes. Or maybe just right after you click the button. Or after your first form gains focus after the second form closes. There're many options.

In case that doesn't work or you could never be bothered enough to implement this thing, there's an easier solution:
Again, give your button a name, e.g. "
When you want its color to return to default, type something along the lines:

```
myPreciousButton.Background = Brushes.LightGrey
```

Not sure how to change the text's color though, I can't be bothered to think about it ;)

Good luck